# How to reference a specific sheet within VBA Code in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

This works perfectly, but I only want it to reference a single sheet instead of every sheet in the workbook

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()

Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "AA120").End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next
For Each c In Range("AA5:AA120" & LastRow)

    If c.Value = "0" Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf c.Value > "0" Then
        c.Activate
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next

On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by "*reference a single sheet instead of every sheet*". Describe the case that you find "odd": what do you do, and what happens after that?

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you only need to insert this code in one sheet which ever you want. Rightclick on sheet name(tab) and select "view code", then paste this code. BUT! If this runs on every sheet, then you also need to delete code from "This Workbook" --> (Alt+F11) and select "This workbook", then erase this code from there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

instead.
According to the great [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx), "The events and their procedure declarations are fixed. You must not alter the name or parameter list of an event procedure." (I do not have a system with Office to test it).

You would insert your `Sub` in a sheet module, and it will work only on that sheet.